# Move scraped data into CSV File

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Two part question.... (please keep in mind I am new to webscraping and BSoup!)
I was able to create a code that grabs the Subject of posts on a forum. But as of right now it only grabs the stuff from page 1 of the forum. I want it to be able to grab all the pages at once, but not exactly sure how to go about this. 
I read online that when the URL changes slightly you could alter that so that it iterates through multiple pages.

The url I wish to scrape is: 
http://thailove.net/bbs/board.php?bo_table=ent
and page 2 is the original url + "&page=2"
Would something like this work?:
    base_url + "&page=" str(2)

Secondly, I can't seem to be able to export the parsed data into a CSV file
This is my attempt at parsing and exporting the data:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import csv

my_url = 'http://thailove.net/bbs/board.php?bo_table=ent'

uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

containers = page_soup.findAll("td",{"class":"td_subject"})
for container in containers:
    subject = container.a.contents[0]
    print("subject: ", subject)

with open('ThaiLove.csv', 'w') as f:
csv_writer = csv.writer(f)
for subject in containers:
        value = subject.a.string
        if value:
                csv_writer.writerow([value.encode('utf-8')])
```

Comment: What happens when you try to write the csv?

Comment: @snapcrack It creates a csv file with the contents of: b'\n                    \xec\x9d\xb4 \xea\xb2\x8c\xec\x8b\x9c\xeb\xac\xbc\xec\x9d\x80 \xeb\xac\xbb\xea\xb3\xa0\xeb\x8b\xb5\xed\x95\x98\xea\xb8\xb0 \xea\xb2\x8c\xec\x8b\x9c\xed\x8c\x90\xec\x9c\xbc\xeb\xa1\x9c \xec\x9d\xb4\xeb\x8f\x99 \xeb\x90\x98\xec\x97\x88\xec\x8a\xb5\xeb\x8b\x88\xeb\x8b\xa4.                                    '
Not sure what's going on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few problems. First, you don't encode here. So it should be:

```
containers = soup.findAll("td",{"class":"td_subject"})
for container in containers:
    subject = container.a.contents[0]
    print("subject: ", subject)

import csv

with open('ThaiLove.csv', 'w') as f:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(f)
    for subject in containers:
        value = subject.a.contents[0]
        if value:
            csv_writer.writerow([value])
```

all without encoding in UTF-8. Which gives me:

```
"\n                    미성년자도 이용하는 게시판이므로 글 수위를 지켜주세요.                    "\n"\n                    방꺽너이 방야이운하 수상보트를 타고 가서 볼만한 곳..                    "\n"\n                    방콕의 대표 야시장 - 딸랏롯파이2                    "\n"\n                    공항에서 제일 가까운 레드썬 마사지                    "\n"\n
```

and so on.

Second, you seem to be writing the wrong thing to your csv. You want to essentially copy the code from your `findAll` function to the write function. So instead of `subject.a.string` you use `container.a.contents`.

As far as scraping the succeeding pages, if you've figured out the pagination format of the website, that should work fine.

Comment: Thanks for the help on converting to CSV that seemed to do the trick.